# private type ..error

Tags: java

can anyone tell me why I get this error?

> illegal start of expression 
> `private int confirm;`

and also

> illegal start of expression 
>  `private File soundFile3 = new File("merge.wav");`

If I remove the word "private" the compiler doesn't show any errors.
The code is part of a public method.
Why?

Thank you.

the code is:

```
private int confirm;
        confirm = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(this,
                "Different sample size....",
                "JOin", JOptionPane.OK_CANCEL_OPTION);
        if (confirm != JOptionPane.OK_OPTION) {
            return;
        }

private File soundFile3 = new File("merge.wav");
```

Comment: can you show us the full code, the relevant bits of this class and the enclosing function? Really it sounds like you're putting in `private` members inside a function.

Comment: that's actually a function (method in Java) If I remove "private" everything is ok. The method : public void joinFiles ()

Answer (score 5):

private keyword cannot be used inside methods. it can be used to declare class fields or methods:

```
class Foo {
  private int num; //private can be specified here
  public void foo() {
     int s = 1;
     int k = num+s; //no private here
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the explanation...so I should turn the method into a class (a subclass) if I wanted to use private..(using the inheritance concept)..Is that correct?

Comment: in java there is no methods without classes.

Answer (score 3):

I guess you cannot put an access modifies except `final` in a method.  It makes no sense to have a private modifier for a method level variable.  As methods variables are created in their separate stack and destroyed when the scope is lost.

Answer (score 1):

You should use access modifiers only on class members, not local variables.

Local variables are always visible only in the scope of the block where they were declared. So, if you declare a variable in your method, that variable will be visible only within that method. So, no need to use `private` there. I mean, no need even if you could.